# iOS Webview UI Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, wkwebview, xcode-ui-testing

Unable to access UI elements during UI testing of an iOS application based on ionic framework. For instance, I would like to tap the button with the label "home Home".

Below is my debugDescription of the app showing the element hierarchy.

```
Element subtree:

 →Application, 0x600000398bb0, pid: 18354, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}},    label: 'FastlaneHelper'
  Window, 0x6000003998b0, Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
  Other, 0x600000398c80, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
    Other, 0x600000398d50, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      WebView, 0x600000398e20, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
        Other, 0x600000398ef0, traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
          Other, 0x600000398fc0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}}
            Other, 0x600000399090, {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}}
              Other, 0x600000380750, traits: 146029019136, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
                Other, 0x600000399230, traits: 146029019136, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: 'Ionic App'
                  Other, 0x6000003994a0, traits: 146029019136, {{0.0, 686.0}, {414.0, 51.0}}
                    Button, 0x6000003997e0, traits: 146297454600, {{0.0, 687.0}, {138.0, 49.0}}, label: 'home Home'
                    Button, 0x600000399640, traits: 146297454592, {{138.0, 687.0}, {138.0, 49.0}}, label: 'information circle-outline About'
                    Button, 0x600000399710, traits: 146297454592, {{276.0, 687.0}, {138.0, 49.0}}, label: 'contacts outline Contact'
                  Other, 0x600000399570, traits: 146029019136, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: 'home Home, tab panel'
                    Other, 0x600000399300, traits: 146029019136, {{90.0, 30.0}, {234.0, 23.0}}
                      StaticText, 0x6000003993d0, traits: 146029019200, {{183.0, 30.0}, {48.0, 23.0}}, label: 'Home'
                    Other, 0x6000003809c0, traits: 146029084672, {{16.0, 77.0}, {382.0, 28.0}}, label: 'Welcome to Ionic!', value: 2
                      StaticText, 0x6000003808f0, traits: 146029084736, {{16.0, 76.0}, {190.0, 29.0}}, label: 'Welcome to Ionic!', value: 2
                    Other, 0x600000380b60, traits: 146029019136, {{16.0, 119.0}, {382.0, 36.0}}
                      StaticText, 0x600000380a90, traits: 146029019200, {{16.0, 119.0}, {368.0, 36.0}}, label: 'This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.'
                    Other, 0x600000380680, traits: 146029019136, {{16.0, 169.0}, {382.0, 36.0}}
                      StaticText, 0x600000380820, traits: 146029019200, {{16.0, 169.0}, {117.0, 18.0}}, label: 'Take a look at the'
                      Other, 0x600000399160, traits: 146029019136, {{133.0, 172.0}, {84.0, 15.0}}
                        StaticText, 0x6000003805b0, traits: 146029019200, {{132.0, 172.0}, {85.0, 15.0}}, label: 'src/pages/'
                      StaticText, 0x600000399a50, traits: 146029019200, {{16.0, 169.0}, {377.0, 36.0}}, label: 'directory to add or change tabs, update any existing page or create new pages.'
    ScrollView, 0x60000039b790, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
Window, 0x60000039b860, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
  StatusBar, 0x60000039b930, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 20.0}}
    Other, 0x60000039ba00, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 20.0}}
    Other, 0x60000039bad0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 20.0}}
      Other, 0x60000039bc70, traits: 8388608, {{6.0, 0.0}, {39.0, 20.0}}
      Other, 0x60000039bd40, traits: 8388608, {{50.0, 0.0}, {14.0, 20.0}}, label: '3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars', value: SSID
      Other, 0x60000039be10, traits: 8389120, {{181.0, 0.0}, {56.0, 20.0}}, label: '12:32 AM'
      Other, 0x60000039bee0, traits: 8388608, {{383.0, 0.0}, {26.0, 20.0}}, label: '87% battery power'
```

I tried accessing the element these ways with no success:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let tabs = app.tabBars
tabBars.buttons["Home"].tap()

let app = XCUIApplication()
let tabs = app.windows.tabBars
tabBars.buttons["Home"].tap()

let app = XCUIApplication()
let tabs = app.windows.webViews.tabBars
tabBars.buttons["Home"].tap()
```

Even tried including "Other" elements from the element hierarchy, but the test failed. Can anyone please help us with the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't search for tab bars as there are no tab bars in your app. There may be something visually similar to tab bars but it's just HTML content. You should look for web views and then for buttons or static texts. Something like:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let web = app.webViews
web.buttons["home Home"].tap()
```